# Plotting multiple graphs with different colour on matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure

I want to draw two graphs in Matlab with different colors. Then I want a box in the upper right corner which names each of the two graphs. The code that I am writing is:

```
x=1:1:max
%err_t_coupled,err_t_uncoupled are arrays
figure
plot(x, err_t_coupled,'red',x, err_t_uncoupled,'blue') 
legend('uncoupled','coupled','Location','Northeast') 
title('Maximum error') 
xlabel('Iterations') 
ylabel('Maximum error wrt D-Norm')
```

It produces the desired graph. However in the top right corner, it draws a **red** line for both coupled and uncoupled. I instead want red for coupled and **blue** for uncoupled. Any solutions?

Comment: It works for me: red and blue lines in legend. Only that they are reversed. You could try `legend('coupled','uncoupled','Location','Northeast') `

Comment: Is the box in upper right showing different colours for both coupled and uncoupled. It is showing same for me

Comment: Different colours. I just defined some random `x`, `err_t_coupled`, `err_t_uncoupled` and pasted your code.

Comment: Wait. You mentioned `err_t_coupled`, `err_t_uncoupled` are arrays. Now I see the problem

Answer (score 3):

The problem has to do with the fact that `err_t_coupled` and `err_t_uncoupled` are arrays, not vectors.

This will work:

```
x=1:1:max
%err_t_coupled,err_t_uncoupled are arrays
figure
h1 = plot(x, err_t_coupled,'red');
hold on
h2 = plot(x, err_t_uncoupled,'blue');
legend([h1(1) h2(1)], 'coupled','uncoupled','Location','Northeast') 
title('Maximum error') 
xlabel('Iterations') 
ylabel('Maximum error wrt D-Norm')
```